# How can I output two separate lists in terraform to show the instances and port numbers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to get my terraform output to fit the following schema.

1.2.3.4:80

I want to have this dynamically work without limitations. The following code would work:

```
output "servers-web-servers" {
    value = join(":", [aws_instance.servers[0].public_ip, aws_security_group_rule.allow-web-server-inbound-servers[0].from_port])
}
```

However, this would only output correctly for the first values in the index.

Another strategy I have tried is the following:

```
output "servers-web-servers" {
    value = join(", ", concat(aws_instance.servers.*.public_ip, aws_security_group_rule.allow-web-server-inbound-servers.*.from_port))
}
```

which would output something like this:

```
servers-web-servers = "1.2.3.4, 5.6.7.8, 80, 8080"
```

Which is slightly closer, but not quite right. Different iterations of using * for the more simplistic setup has resulted in errors stating:

```
| aws_instance.servers is tuple with 2 elements
| aws_security_group_rule.allow-web-server-inbound-servers is tuple with 2 elements
```

The goal here would just to be to dynamically generate the output to list both the ip address and the port of the respective servers so that the user can easily copy and paste it into their browser without hardcoding values or expecting thQe user to only have a set number (e.g. they may need 2 for one test and 4 for another). I feel like I'm close here, but I'm missing some piece of information or a different technique. Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: Your example schema consists of a single ip address. But in your question you indicate you want multiple ip address:port pairs. Do you want a list of strings as the final output?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that for every aws instance in `aws_instance.servers` there is a single corresponding security group in `aws_security_group_rule.allow-web-server-inbound-servers`

If that is the case, then these are two lists of equal length. We can use [terraform for expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html) to iterate through one list with the index and use [string interpolation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#user-string-variables) to build up the desired string:

Here is an example:

```
locals {
  instances = [
    { public_ip = "1.1.1.1" },
    { public_ip = "2.2.2.2" }

  ]


  security_groups = [
    { from_port = 80 },
    { from_port = 8080 },
  ]
}

output "server-web-servers" {
  value = [for idx, instance in local.instances :
  "${instance.public_ip}:${local.security_groups[idx].from_port}"]
}
```

Which results in:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

Plan: 0 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Changes to Outputs:
  + server-web-servers = [
      + "1.1.1.1:80",
      + "2.2.2.2:8080",
    ]
```